# Is there any tool that can create a .SLN off a target project that has projects references?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, solution, csproj

Is there any tool where I could something like this:

tool.exe myProj.csprj

and have it create an on the fly SLN for the project and its referenced projects, and open VS with that SLN?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio is a pretty good tool.  It will automatically create the .sln if you open a .csproj file that doesn't have a .sln file with the same name.

Comment: But it will not handle referenced projects. If Project B uses things from Project A, it should create a solution with both projects, and set up the references. By opening project B straight from VS, it will load Project B but complain about the missing references.

Comment: To the person who marked for close, according to the rules: "**If your question generally covers [..] software tools commonly used by programmers**[..] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

[...]Questions about [..] software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. 
I believe that a tool that generates Visual Studio Solution files would qualify as a tool that is primarily for programming, don't you?

Comment: doubt there is such a tool. But the principle is not that hard so maybe you can craft it yourself: parse the projects for referenced projects (recursively), add them to a solution.